# Cannot boot normally, without restarting lightdm (or gdm)

Tags: 13.04, login, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

I had a problem precisely described here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/ubuntu-lightdm-black-screen-when-using.html, black screen with blinking cursor instead of login screen.
I've switched to `gdm` using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` -- but faced the same problem, now loading process stops on "red-white Ubuntu dots" (without activity under this splash). And to login, I still need to restart display manager: Ctrl+Alt+F1 and `sudo service gdm restart`.

How to make Ubuntu to boot normally?

Comment: What graphics card and drivers are you using? The main reason this hasn't been answered is that its missing significant detail.

Comment: @Andy Radeon HD 5670. X.org drivers or `fglrx-updates` -- no difference.

Comment: Are you using any proprietory drivers? You may want to disable those.

Comment: If you can re-install x server: sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg , sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg , sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg