# black screen on booting

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, gdm

I've been working with Ubuntu on my lenovo for awhile. after heavy using I started to face the black screen when I reboot. Cursor at the top left blinking with the sound of rebooting. I still see the mouse pointer. I had to hold Ctrl+Alt with F1 to work around that. After Entering my credentials, I typed in "sudo service lightdm --full-restart", so it works fine. I still face this issue every time I reboot. My question is what might cause this problem ? How do I fix it permanently ? .

Nota: I had to replace lightdm with gdm in oreder to work, although, I don't like gdm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What graphics card/drivers are you using?  You said after heavy use this began, that seems unrelated but not insignificant.  Try:

[Cannot boot normally, without restarting lightdm (or gdm)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312339/cannot-boot-normally-without-restarting-lightdm-or-gdm?rq=1)

or

[Ubuntu Opens in Black Screen Using Lightdm But Working When Using GDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337116/ubuntu-opens-in-black-screen-using-lightdm-but-working-when-using-gdm?rq=1)

Comment: the issue was with the lightdm, I had to remove it and install gdm instead. thank you